# TeXmacs crashes when open "grid panels"?

Tags: texmacs

From the latest update of Arch Linux TeXmacs doesn't work very well.

When I want open a "grid panel" (e.g. Format -> Color...) (e.g, select a Greek letter in Math mode from the suitable interface botton) it crashes with this error.

`TeXmacs] With linked TrueType support
Throwing segmentation fault
Error message:
  segmentation fault
System information:
  TeXmacs version  : 1.99.5
  Built by         : builduser
  Building date    : 2017-12-22T12:40:31
  Operating system : linux-gnu
  Vendor           : pc
  Processor        : x86_64
  Crash date       : sab  6 gen 2018, 00.46.13, CET
Editor status:
  Root path          : [ 1 ]
  Current path       : [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  Shifted path       : [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  Physical selection : [ 1, 0, 0 ] -- [ 1, 0, 0 ]
Backtrace of C++ stack:
  texmacs.bin : () + 0x857af6
  texmacs.bin : () + 0x6c5342
  /usr/lib/libc.so.6 : () + 0x348e0
  [0x559113d1e4e0]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'string'`

Could anyone help me, please? 
Thanks, regards.

Comment: TeXmacs is not TeX. Some questions about it might be on topic, for instance interactions between TeX and TeXmacs; however, specific questions on the program are off-topic.

Comment: TeXmacs segfaulting doesn't really smell like a TeX problem to me. I would recommend either the Arch forums or the Arch Linux subreddit; they are more likely to be able to help (and if not, maybe the TeXmacs project itself). Also, maybe try the binary from the TeXmacs website directly and see if that throws the same error as the packaged Arch version.

Comment: I'm so sorry! If I've to remove the question I'll do it.
At the time I publish the solution: 
1) First command: setenv QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE windows
2) Second command: texmacs

Comment: Please consider supporting the proposed creation of a TeXmacs SE site here: https://area51.stackexchange.com where such kind of questions can be discussed.